# PHP - How to install PDO driver? (Windows)

Tags: php, mysql, windows, pdo

I am setting up PHP and MySQL (Maria DB) on Windows 8.1. I edited php.ini file and uncommented the following lines:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

But unfortunately I cannot connect to database because there are no pdo drivers shown in phpinfo output. So, when I try to establish database connection, an exception is thrown:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'
```

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Make sure, that the php_pdo_mysql.dll is in your php\ext folder. Also, post your DSN string. Perhaps you want to try to restart the webserver, if you use one.

Answer (score 11):

Finaly I managed to settle this stuff. I corrected extension_dir entry (absolute file path was needed) in php.ini file and database connection began to work.

Comment: Thanks ! with absolute path (like d:/DevEnv/php7.3/ext) instead of relative path (ext as suggested in php.ini file) it's work. mysql pdo drive is found

Comment: In windows, all I did was uncomment `extension_dir = "ext"`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the extension_dir of your current apache directory, i installed 2 php versions and apache, and the problem was in wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.23\bin\php.ini , the path of ext was incorrect

Answer (score 1):

In the php.ini file, just below ;On Windows, uncomment 'extension_dir = "ext"'

It worked for me.
[image: php in snippet screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to locate the php.ini file for the version I am using,
and uncomment the line `extension=pdo_pgsql` for my case as I would like to use postgres
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case (windows pc) the extension_dir folder was set default to ext. However i got the same error "could not find driver". So i replaced the path to extension directoy with absolute path as below, and it worked.

php.ini

```
;extension_dir = ext
extension_dir = "C:\dev\php-8.3.4-Win32-vs16-x64\ext"
```