# Laravel PDO could not find driver

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, pdo

I'm trying to set up a SQL Server DB with my Laravel project.

Things I did:

- Download DLL from Microsoft site (version 32 for my php 5.6.25) and copied them to my php /ext folder.
- Added **extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll** and **extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll** to my PHP.INI file (and the extensions are showing in my phpinfo()).
- Changed my `database.php` config file to `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv')`

BUT: when I try to migrate my database I get the error:

```
[PDOException] 
could not find driver
```

Is there anything I missed? Some bad config I have to re check?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**
I'm using Wamp x32 on a Win7 x64 OS.

**EDIT 2:**
This is the error I get when running migration using "-vvv"

```
Exception trace:
 () at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:55
 PDO->__construct() at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:55
 Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createConnection() at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\SqlServerConnector.php:32
 Illuminate\Database\Connectors\SqlServerConnector->connect() at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory.php:61
 Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\Database\Connectors\{closure}() at n/a:n/a call_user_func() at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:924
 Illuminate\Database\Connection->getPdo() at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\DatabaseConnection.php:792
 Illuminate\Database\Connection->reconnectIfMissingConnection() at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:677
 Illuminate\Database\Connection->run() at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:349
 Illuminate\Database\Connection->select() at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder.php:55
 Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder->hasTable() at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\DatabaseMigrationRepository.php:141
 Illuminate\Database\Migrations\DatabaseMigrationRepository->repositoryExists()at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php:404 Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->repositoryExists() at C:\wamp\www\mentoringsecure_html\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand.php:103
 Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand->prepareDatabase() at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand.php:58
 Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand->fire() at n/a:n/a call_user_func_array() at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:507
 Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:169
 Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:256
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:155
 Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:794
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:186
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:107
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() at C:\wamp\www\mentoring\secure_html\artisan:36
```

Comment: On which OS are you ?

Comment: I'm using Wamp x32 on a Win7 x64 OS.

Comment: did you update .env file?

Comment: ok check if the extension is loaded correctly in the `phpinfo()` if it is loaded you will be able to use it

Comment: The .env file has been updated and the extensions are showing in phpinfo()

Comment: try to run the migrations with `-vvv` and post the output or link to it.

Comment: Try running `php artisan config:clear`. This will clear any previous database settings.

Comment: Tried cleaning the database settings, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Have you install PDO driver ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948767/php-how-to-install-pdo-driver-windows

Comment: Yes, PDO is installed and showing up in `phpinfo()`

Comment: When you run `phpinfo()` is this via `php -r "phpinfo();"` or are you actually running it via a web server?

Comment: I have a php file and I call that file from my browser

Answer (score 0):

**First** : download the correct dll (corresponding to your php version)
-php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll
-php_sqlsrv.dll
**Then** : Put them in wamp/bin/php/php_yourversion/ext
**Finally** : enable extensions on **both php.ini**
- Wamp use one php.ini => for browser
- PHP use another php.ini => for terminal