# PHP with PDO using XAMPP and Workbench

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xampp

I'm a begginer in PHP and I'm trying to connect my application with database using PDO.

```
$dbName = "new_schema";
$this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbName", "root", "");
```

When I try to run my application, this is the output of browser:

```
Fatal error: in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\application\model-database.class.php on line 10
```

Line 10 is this:

```
$this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbName", "root", "");
```

In Workbench, Hostname is set as *localhost*, port *3308* and username *root*. No password. Connection name is *Local instance mysqlweb*.

In Xampp, Mysql run on port 3308.

Thanks very much for any help. :)

EDIT:

[This is the browser output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6iRw.png)

Now, the error is **could not find driver**.

Comment: What is the fatal error you're getting?

Comment: Not enough information

Comment: MySQL default port is 3306. If you use another one, you must define it in your dns string.

Comment: Thanks. How can I define this DNS string?

Comment: This is your [**DSN** (Data Source Name)](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php): `mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbName`. Add `;port=3308` to it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Changed, partly helped. Now, I can display a static site, but when I try to display a site with data from db, this error occurs: **could not find driver
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\application\model-database.class.php:250 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\application\con-realised.class.php(18): ModDatabaze->getRealised() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\application\con-index.php(33): ConRealised->getResult() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\application\model-database.class.php on line 250**

Comment: But I have data in this table.

Comment: This is the code: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM `realised`\";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
$host       = '127.0.0.1'; //or localhost
$database   = 'mysql';
$port       = 3306;
$user       = 'root';
$password   = '';

try {
    $this->connection = new PDO($database . ":host=" . $host . ';port=' . $port, $user, $password);
    $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $this->connection;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the driver in the PHP.INI file?

In your PHP.INI search for `extension=php_pdo.dll` and `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` and remove the `;` in front of them. Save the file and restart the XAMPP-server.

### Edit

---

I haven't had the opportunity to run it my self, not on my dev machine today, but you can try running this code in a new script to see if you get some more details on the error. I have set it up for throwing and catching errors, as well as dumping the `phpinfo()` page to see if PDO is enabled and MySQL drivers are showing up.

```
<?php

class DBTest 
{
    private $dbname;
    private $host;
    private $port;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $driver;

    private $db;
    
    public __construct($username, $password, $dbname = "", $host = "127.0.0.1", $port = 3306, $driver = "mysql")
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->port = $port;
        $this->driver = $driver;
    }
    
    private function getDSN()
    {
        return sprintf("%s:host=%s;dbname=%s;port=%d", $this->driver, $this->host, $this->dbname, $this->port);
    }

    private function connect()
    {
        try
        {
            $this->db = new PDO($this->getDSN(), $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function getRealised()
    {
        if($this->db == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM realised";

        try
        {
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql); 
            $query->execute();
            while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
            {
                print_r($row);
            }
        }
        catch(PDO_Exception $e)
        {
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

$dbtest = new DBTest("root", "", "new_schema", "127.0.0.1", 3308, "mysql");
print("Created object");

if($dbtest->connect())
{
    echo "Connected to DB";
}

if($dbtest->getRealised())
{
    echo "Database queried";
}

phpinfo();
```

Comment: Thanks for help. The `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` was already there without `;` in front of it. I added `extension=php_pdo.dll` and restarted XAMPP. But the error **could not find driver** is still there.

Comment: Hm... Perhaps there is a problem with your paths. Check this answer to see if that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948767/php-how-to-install-pdo-driver-windows

Comment: The path to extesion directory is correct (and is set as absolute). Both of these extensions are in this directory.

Comment: @JennyG. Added some code to try to get more info on error.