# Drupal: PDOException: could not find driver in lock_may_be_available()

Tags: php, pdo, drupal

I am running Drupal on my local machine using Windows and recently I opened a project solution within Visual Studio.  Upon opening the solution, it asked me to install PHP7 extensions via the Microsoft Web Platform Installer.  After these extensions were installed, when I navigate to my local Drupal site, I get the following error:

`PDOException: could not find driver in lock_may_be_available()`

I did do some research before I decided to ask this question and it seems that I'm just missing this driver.

If this is the problem, how do I install the right PDO driver for Drupal?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's not driver for Drupal, but for PHP. It's name should be "pdo_mysql", "php_pdo_mysql" or similar, depending on platform. Since you are on windows you should look for a way to install it there. I.e. check this SO post:

[PHP - How to install PDO driver? (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948767/php-how-to-install-pdo-driver-windows)

BTW, will you site really run on windows server? If not, my advise is to develop on virtual machine, so you'll have the same development environment, as production will be (most likely linux, right?).